# How to launch remote X app using X-forwarding and get application grouping

Tags: desktop-application, gnome, x11-forwarding

I have a desktop file which allows me to launch a process on a remote host (actually a vm) using ssh -X. This will then display on my local machine.

What I cannot do is persuade Gnome to group different windows of this application under one desktop icon. My example is emacs, but I have the same problem with Pycharm.

Here is my .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]                                                                                                                                                                          
Type=Application                                                                              
Encoding=UTF-8                                                                                
Name=MYemacs                                                                                 
Comment=emacs on dev box                                                                      
Exec=ssh -X -T rhost 'emacs'                                                                    
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/emacs.png                                            
Terminal=false
```

Can someone advise me on what I am missing, please? Thanks.